# Next Auth middleware and protected folder

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I am building a NextJS app and I have a series of routers at `pages/dashboard/*` that I want to protect. I am using Prisma but for the moment what I want to do is to being able to access the routes only if the user is logged in. I am using Google provider and everything is setup correctly.
This is my middleware.ts

```js
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard"] }
```

Is very simple. This is my [...nextAuth] file

import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { prisma } from "@/lib/db/prisma"

```js
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

I have the secrets in a .env.local also the NEXTAUTH_SECRET created locally. The problem I am facing is that whenever the user goes to dashboard it gets redirected to the login, once you login the page is still not accessible and keeps asking for login. I noticed that the `useSession` returns me the data in the browser, but apparently the token or session in the node side is null.
I have `Next 13.2.4` and `Next Auth ^4.20.1`
I can't figure out why is not working, I tried all the solutions proposed in other questions but none of them works and I am unable to see the dashboard.
Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution, for those who might be in the same situation:
I added the strategy to the next auth options:

```
 session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
```

and now it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot... i was facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **NEXTAUTH_SECRET** on **authOptions**.

```
 export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
},
secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET

}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```